# How to call the API of AppSync in curl from my local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I created an API with AppSync. Now I want to call it with curl, and I get the following error: `You are not authorized to make this call`.

I guessed the following:

```sh
curl -g -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer da2-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -d '{"query":"listMyModelTypes{listMyModelTypes {items {id title}}}"}' https://wuw4mcnvautpl4v5ox33fdzoq.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql
```

Or should I also include the API ID somewhere in the query?

Comment: I suggested to use gql-cli in an answer but it was deleted because it was a duplicate answer. See https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/appsync.html

Answer (score 0):

Making an Appsync query via CURL or Postman depends on getting the request body and headers right.  The required headers depend on auth type.

```sh
# common variables
API_URL='https://<APPSYNC-ID>.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql'
QUERY='query GetImages($t: String!) { images(topic:$t) { edges { cursor } } }'
VARIABLES='{"t":"cats"}' # no spaces!
```

**API Key Auth**:  `x-api-key` header

```sh
API_KEY='da2-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

curl -s -XPOST -H "Content-Type:application/graphql" -H "x-api-key:$API_KEY" -d '{"query": "'"$QUERY"'", "variables": '$VARIABLES'}' $API_URL
```

**Token-based Auth (e.g. Cognito)**:  `Authorization` and `host` headers

```sh
TOKEN='<YOUR JWT AUTH TOKEN HERE>'
HOST='<APPSYNC-ID>.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'

curl -s -XPOST -H "Content-Type:application/graphql" -H "Authorization:$TOKEN" -H "host:$HOST" -d '{"query": "'"$QUERY"'", "variables": '$VARIABLES'}' $API_URL
```