# AWS Appsync GraphQL query silently failing though successful 200 response

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have one React Amplify app running with two environments. One environment is for my wife's blog ([www.riahraineart.com](http://www.riahraineart.com)) and one for my blog ([www.joshmk.com](http://www.joshmk.com)). Both sites are running off the same repo, I'm just configuring the site's differently based on an environment variable I use to retrieve their configurations from a table.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const configData = await API.graphql({
        query: queries.getConfiguration,
        variables: { id: process.env[configIdName] },
      });
      if (configData && isMounted.current)
        setConfig(configData.data.getConfiguration || {});
    }
    if (process.env[configIdName]) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [isMounted, configIdName]);
```

For my site, when I make the GraphQL request for this configuration, it's successful and the site spins up. For my wife's site, this call to the configurations table silently fails. By silent, I mean there's no helpful response being returned from the API even though it's a successful 200 response.

When I open AppSync, go to the two environments and run the queries, I receive the configuration items. I also see them when I open dynamodb.

I'm thinking there could be some expired token for something somewhere but if that was the case, I would think I'd receive a failed response that would state that.

Another possibility could be that my wife had modified the configuration of her site or created a post with some content that the frontend doesn't expect. But in that case, I would atleast expect to see a response from the call to receive her sites configuration.

Thank you beforehand for any insights here!

Comment: Could CORS be the culprit?

Comment: Hmm, well @Norman I'd expect both sites to be failing if CORS was mis-configured.

Comment: What is the result of the buggy query when you run it in the appsync console?  Does the config table item exist as expected in the dynamodb console?  In other words, first try to rule out a backend problem.

Comment: @fedonev yes to both questions. I see the configuration items when I go to their respective environments in AppSync and run the query. And also when looking at the tables in dynamodb, I also see the configuration items. I should have mentioned that above, I'll add that.

Comment: That's helpful!  The AppSync console is a client implementation, making calls like your frontend does.  If the AWS console query returns the expected results, you've narrowed the problem to a frontend problem.  If you need more convincing, execute the buggy query in [cURL or Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70006885/1103511).  I expect it will work fine.  Another test - simulate a null response: what response do you get from AppSync when your client passes well-formed, but non-existent variable input to the query?

Comment: @fedonev when I try a fake configuration item id, the Network tab will give me a generic response on the query, "Failed to load response data: No given identifier found." Though it doesn't error out in a try/catch because it's still a 200. One thing that I want to mention is that the two websites are based off of different branches. When I want to update either one, I will hop between those branches to push the changes. I wonder if some configuration for my site, overwrote the configuration for my wife's. Though this would be strange since that workflow has worked for me for a year.

Comment: I'm going to verify that everything in each aws-exports file looks good.

Comment: Oh yeah, aws-exports.js is just a local thing. So that wouldn't affect the deployed apps. Nevermind. I'm starting to think this might be an auth issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Unfortunately, the solution was pretty specific to my situation so it may not provide too much value for others. Although, I hope it helps with troubleshooting.

After locally switching my backend configuration over to her site using `amplify pull --appId <appId> --envName <envName>` I noticed that the configuration call was now successful. I had forgotten that I had never actually run her site locally, I only hopped to her branch to merge and push.

The site was still not rendering though, which perked my ears for a race condition. I discovered that I had left a checker for some images that was gating render of my topmost component. My wife has a ton of images, so I think this call was taking too long to make the chain of events load items in the correct order, and the page showed blank. Simply removing that check for those images at that point, showed the UI.